# Convert the result of a query to an array of arrays

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

```
$shops = $this->em->getRepository('models\Shop')->findAll();
```

Gives my an array with entities but I need the entity as array.

How do I convert an entity to an array?

Comment: *entity as array* How does entity look like and how would the array look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue.`return get_object_vars($this)` is not a good solution because it also converts internal doctrine object/properties too.After some research i found this class: [EntitySerializer](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary/blob/master/library/Bgy/Doctrine/EntitySerializer.php) which creates clean array or JSON from your entities and removes unnecessary items.The documentation is located [here](http://borisguery.github.com/bgylibrary).For example i used the following code:

```
$patientProfile = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Patientprofile')->findOneByuserid('2222222');
$entitySerializer=new Bgy\Doctrine\EntitySerializer($this->em);
$patientProfile=$entitySerializer->toArray($patientProfile);
```

Comment: How install it in Zend Framework 2? Can you explain like for idiot? :)

Answer (score 16):

Doctrine allows you to specify a hydration mode when executing queries, which let's you change the data type of the results returned. In this case, you need Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY. It does not let you specify this on the default findAll() method, found on the repositories. You will need to write your own DQL for it.

If you need a collection of entites as arrays:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM User u');
$entites = $query->execute(array(), Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

// If you don't have parameters in the query, you can use the getResult() shortcut
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM User u');
$entities = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

If you need a single entity as an array, eg. for a specific ID:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = ?1');
$query->setParameter(1, $id);
$entity = $query->getSingleResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

These methods are defined on [Query](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/doctrine/orm/query.html), and [AbstractQuery](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/doctrine/orm/abstractquery.html).

Comment: But that makes it unpossible to use with the abstract EntityRepository->findAll() method.